# Create a table from the results of a recursive query (with statement)

Tags: sqlite, recursive-query, with-statement

I want to make a new (persistent) table from the results of a recursive query in SQLite.
For instance, let's make a table with columns `(n, fct)`, where `n` denotes a natural number and `fct` its factorial:

```
-- factorial of n = 0, 1, ..., 5
WITH RECURSIVE fact_i (n, fct) AS (
     VALUES (0, 1)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT n+1, fct * (n+1) FROM fact_i
     WHERE n < 5)
SELECT * FROM fact_i;
```

which results in

```
0|1
1|1
2|2
3|6
4|24
5|120
```

However, I'd like to store the results in a persistent table, say `factorials`.

I tried

```
CREATE TABLE factorials (n, fct) AS
WITH RECURSIVE fact_i (n, fct) AS (
     VALUES (0, 1)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT n+1, fct * (n+1) FROM fact_i
     WHERE n < 5)
SELECT * FROM fact_i;
```

or

```
WITH RECURSIVE fact_i (n, fct) AS (
     VALUES (0, 1)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT n+1, fct * (n+1) FROM fact_i
     WHERE n < 5)
CREATE TABLE factorials (n, fct) AS
SELECT * FROM fact_i;
```

Yet both result in a syntax error.
Is there a way to create such a table in SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible(wrapping with additional `SELECT * FROM ()`):

```
CREATE TABLE factorials AS
SELECT *
FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE fact_i (n, fct) AS (
     VALUES (0, 1)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT n+1, fct * (n+1) FROM fact_i
     WHERE n < 5)
SELECT * FROM fact_i) s;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4e2c26591eacf1c3dbe76a37187db13a)**

EDIT:

Actually, all you need to do is removing column list from `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE factorials AS
WITH RECURSIVE fact_i (n, fct) AS (
     VALUES (0, 1)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT n+1, fct * (n+1) FROM fact_i
     WHERE n < 5)
SELECT * FROM fact_i;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4b7154fd21cc06c703dccc737717f751)**

Comment: what is the final `s` at the end of line 9?

Comment: @AlQuemist Subquery alias, but the subquery part could be skipped, check revised version